# Diagonalizing quadrics

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am doing the following exercise. 
Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic not 2. 
a) Show that any quadratic form in $n$ variables can be "diagonalized"
by changing coordinates to be a sum of at most $n$ squares.

b) Show that the number of squares depends only on the quadric.

I was able to do the first part, but I am stuck on the second part.
I would appreciate any help/hint. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

You can go through the hints provided by Prof. Vakil on the bottom of [page 162](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf) to page 163 of his FOA book. I do not think I can provide better hints than he did.

Comment: I am doing the same exercise, could you possibly explain me what it means by the number of squares depends "only on the quadric"? I am a bit confused by the wording here...

Comment: @user201886: Assume we are computers who cannot "think" other than being programmed. Now if we are given the quadratic and an algorithm to diagonalize it, what will happen if the algorithm were tried multiple times on the same quadratic? For example the quadratic $xy-yz+xz-xw$ can be viewed as a quadratic in $k[x,y,z,w]$, and you can work inductively from $k[x]$ to $k[x,y]$, and so on. But you can also view it as in $k[z,w,y,x]$ or even $k[\frac{z-w}{2},\frac{z+w}{2},y,x]$. It is not obvious that the same procedure give you the same number of positive/negative squares.

Comment: @user201886 I should add that there is no "positive/negative squares". It is all positive. I was confused. Sorry.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you very much for the clear explanation!